# Codebase attribute appears in <Applet> tag

Tags: java, html, applet

We have a piece of code that calls an applet and the applet tag is configured with the 'code' and 'archive' attributes, something like this:

```
<applet code='some.class' Archive='absolute path'/>
```

In some of the environments the applet however doesn't load properly. We run traces and found that the 'Codebase' attribute appeared in the applet tag with the session cookie value in these environments.

We don't understand what and why is inserting the codebase attribute into the applet tag. Could someone shed some light on this? We run a lot of network monitoring but no third party components inserts this in the call.

Comment: Now I look at the two posts more closely, it is obvious you are correct.  My apologies.  I cannot remove the 'close vote', but have deleted the noise.  As to the answer. I don't immediately know, but browsers will often interpret the same HTML differently.  Make sure it is [validated](http://validator.w3.org/) before puzzling over further differences between environments.  If the problems persist with valid (not a single error or warning) HTML, it is time to look into actual makes & versions of browsers & JREs.

Comment: Oh, and don't 'self close' the applet element.  The `applet` element was only valid up to HTML 3.2, and the philosophy of 'let's make all HTML elements self-closing' only came in later.  ;)  I would also avoid upper-case in any HTML element or attribute (not invalid, just unnecessary) & adding `.class` to the code attribute, which is incorrect but tolerated.

Comment: That's no problem, thanks for the answer. I guess my question here was how the codebase parameter appears in the response in the applet tag when it was not specified in the original request when calling the applet?